# window.focus not working javascript; window.close works though?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Objective: Warn User before leaving parent page if they have a Web Based Training Pop-up open.
If they click cancel to stay on the page, I want the the focus back on the pop-up.  Right now, it stays minimized and it's a problem.

This code works and the pop-up closes when I test:

```
window.open('', 'Popup').close();
```

If I test this, it does nothing:

```
window.open('', 'Popup').focus();
```

Full script:

```
window.onload = function () {
     window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {             

         if (window.open('', 'Popup') == null) {
             return undefined;
         }

          setTimeout(function () {
              setTimeout(function () {
                window.open('', 'Popup').focus();
            }, 1000);
        }, 1);

         var confirmationMessage = 'If you navigate away from this page, your open workshop will be closed';                   

         (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE                
         return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
     });
```

Comment: Can you put your code in a fiddle like this one? http://jsfiddle.net/khurram_khu/507ww3o2/

Comment: I'll have to investigate and mock something up with a pop-up, not sure i have the experience to make it an easy task....

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be OK. But you can try below code and see if it works.

```
var url ='your URL'
var popWin = window.open(url, "Popup");
popWin.focus();
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.  

My url is dynamic so I'm not sure how I would assign it.

I did try the following wit the same results:

var existingWin = window.open('', 'Popup');
existingWin.focus();

What's so bizarre is if i change .focus() to close()  
It executes and closes.

Also for kicks I did try FireFox and it had the same results.